# Como anular evento click no site

Tags: jquery, html

Utilizo um plugin `jQuery` que gera um menu lateral escondido e ao clicar no botão, o menu surge, deslocando o conteúdo do site para o lado. O problema é que os elementos do site continuam "clicáveis" e o menu não fecha automaticamente se eu clicar fora dele.

Com isso, criei o script abaixo:

```
$('.wrapp').on('click', function(){
    if ( ($('#sidr').is(':visible')) ) {
        $(this).click(false);
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr');
    }
});
```

A principio, ele deve executar quando clicado em qualquer elemento dentro da `div .wrapp`, fechando o menu (id `#sidr`) e anulando o possível click alternativo.

Apesar do menu estar fechando direitinho, ainda consigo clicar em qualquer link fora do menu.

Melhor explicação na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode criar um jsFiddle com um exemplo?

Comment: Difícil, pois o menu requer scripts externos. Mas vou tentar exemplificar melhor com imagens.

Answer (score 7):

Podes, por exemplo, registar um evento de clique na página que vai cancelar o clique em determinados elementos se o teu menu estiver aberto/visível:

```js
$("body")
    .find('a:not(#meuElementoClicavel)')
    .on("click", function(e) {
        if ($('#meuElementoClicavel').is(':visible')){
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[**Ver Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/f1Lt2k9u/)

No exemplo prático dá para ver que com o elemento `#meuElementoClicavel` visível, os *links* da página não funcionam.

[**Neste outro exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/f1Lt2k9u/1/), o código está presente na página, mas como o elemento `#meuElementoClicavel` não está visível, os *links* funcionam normalmente.

---

Aplicando isto ao caso prático do teu código na pergunta:

```js
$('.wrapp').on('click', function(){
    if ($('#sidr').is(':visible')) {
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Embora no teu caso prático outras coisas podem influenciar o correto funcionamento da ação de "cancelar" o clique...

Comment: Já tinha tentado por `return false` e não adiantou. Vou testar a segunda opção sua, mas o problema é que preciso anular qualquer clic no site, desde links até inputs e tals.

Comment: De forma a cancelar o clique em todos os elementos menos o elemento X, podes usar: `$("body > *").not("#meuElementoClicavel").on("click", function(e) { ...});` Ver exemplo no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/f1Lt2k9u/2/).

Comment: Testei deixando somente o `return false` e funcionou!! Porém, eu preciso executar a função de fechar o menu, então eu coloquei `$.sidr('close', 'sidr');` antes do `return`e  não funcionou mais. Se eu colocar o `return false` antes, também não funciona.

Answer (score 3):

Se `.wrapp` for uma overlay sobre os objetos clicáveis, substitua: `$(this).click(false);` por: [`event.stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('.wrapp').on('click', function(event){
    if ( ($('#sidr').is(':visible')) ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr');
    }
});
```

Mas se os objetos clicáveis estão dentro de `.wrapp` use o: [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('.wrapp').on('click', function(event){
    if ( ($('#sidr').is(':visible')) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr');
    }
});
```

Comment: Não deu, os links continuam executando.

Comment: @Ricardo então o `.wrapp` não esta exatamente como um overlay...

Comment: Eu posso estar colocando o elemento errado. Eu coloquei a classe `.wrapp` pois ela é a classe das `divs` dos conteúdos, dentro de cada bloco há links, textos, etc.

Comment: @Ricardo fiz uma edição na resposta, e fique atento ao parâmetro event na function: `function(event){`

Comment: O `event.preventDefault();` também não funcionou. :(